# Xcode 6 Launchscreen.xib with different assets for iPad landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using the LaunchScreen, which was introduced in Xcode 6, can I define different assets to use for iPad Landscape and Portrait? Since the traits for both iPad orientations are the same (which is a pity, btw) I can not distinguish between the two.

Does that mean, either use the same assets and layout constraints for iPad landscape and portrait or don't use a Launchscreen in a xib or storyboard, but rather resort to the "old way" with two entire screens for portrait and landscape?

Any tricks, that I am overlooking?
I really would like to use Launchscreen.xib, as it seems very convenient to save the storage memory for the different fullscreen images for each screen size.

Comment: Therefore I asked, whether there is any other way to distinguish. I can't believe, that I am the first person having this problem. Btw. sorry for the completely wrong title of the question, that was an older title, which I now edited

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't specify a different image JUST for iPad in landscape. I can do it for iPhone/iPad but not for iPad in landscape. I was thinking to don't use Size classes and use instead a xib like `LaunchScreen-Landscape~ipad.xib` but i don't know if it will be automatically taken then.

Comment: Any update on this guys?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want. The storyboard can't distinguish between iPad portrait and landscape and there is view controller behind it we can manipulate into testing conditions and modifying layout or assets.

I ran into this same problem and the answer was to give it up and use static launch images. Like you, I really wanted to use the storyboard, but it's just not possible currently.

I was trying to do layouts something like this.

[image]
[image]