# iOS Universal Image Assets

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, xcode7, assets

For a new project my client wants to cover all iPhone and iPad sizes. For icons and sprites I'm not really gonna change the shapes of the images, but I'm in a bind with assets for my background images.

Looking at http://iosres.com I was wondering if there is some logic to cover both Landscape and Portrait 3:4 and 9:16 in one asset or should I simply make a set of iPhone and iPad and use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` to figure out what to show before loading my views?

Also I'm wondering what's most effective for all the different device sizes. I know from experience that an iPad 3 wouldn't like to have a background image loaded on 4k resolution and that you want to avoid pixel differences so it won't trigger scaling in UIImageViews. Will iOS automatically figure out that the iPad 3 will use like the @1x variations, whereas the iPad Pro will load the @3x versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes iOS will automatically figure out which image to load at runtime and load @1x @2x or @3x depending upon the type of device. You don't need to do anything like `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` for each image.

**Edit:**

You can also add `~ipad` suffix in image names so iOS will pick the appropriate background image for iPhones and iPads. i.e. `image_name@2x~ipad.png` and `image_name@2x.png`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you also elaborate on the difference between 3:4 and 9:16 on both device-types? Can I make one Asset holding both iPhone (9:16) and iPad (4:3) variations or should I do that myself? The background images are almost always photos and want to have different designs for iPhone and iPad; not just clipping or stretching them.

Comment: Also; can an asset contain both Portrait and Landscape images, which will dynamically change accordingly?

Comment: Ah I found a way to enable iPhone and iPad sections inside the asset! Still can't find Portrait/Landscape features tho.

Comment: And for Portrait/Landscape I think you will have to do that by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've got that figured out now. I noticed in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355198/xcode-6-launchscreen-xib-with-different-assets-for-ipad-landscape-and-portrait that indeed I have to handle orientational situations myself. I'm already using an overlapping CoreController so that won't be an issue. Thanks again!